# Assets 2 field not working properly within 2.6 relationship

Tags: pixelandtonic, relationships, assets

I've got an assets field within a single relationship, using the new 2.6 tags, and I'm having a couple of problems:

1. The assets tag pair only loops once, regardless of how many assets are
   in the field
2. The inner assets tags aren't outputting anything

I've tried all of these combinations, without success:

```
{relationship_field:assets_field}
    {relationship_field:assets_field:url}
{/relationship_field:assets_field}

{relationship_field:assets_field}
    {assets_field:url}
{/relationship_field:assets_field}

{relationship_field:assets_field}
    {url}
{/relationship_field:assets_field}
```

Other relationship tags (e.g. `{relationship_field:title}` ) output as expected.

Am I doing it wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: I was just about to post the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

embed this in your index.html

{exp:channel:entries channel="name_of_your_relationship_channel" dynamic="off"}

```
{parents field="relationship_field"}

{title}
<img src="{asset_field_name}" alt="">

{/parents}
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

if this is not clear for u then look up here 
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#id18

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. It worked for me, allowing multiple image selection in assets.

```
{relationship_field}
    {relationship_field:assets_field parse="inward"}
        {url}
    {/relationship_field:assets_field}
{/relationship_field}
```