# Assets within a relationship field

Tags: assets, relationships

I have tried everything I can think of, but can't get an assets field to output from a relationship.

```
{suggested_products}
    {suggested_products:product_images}
        {product_images:url}
    {/suggested_products:product_images}
{/suggested_products}
```

I found a few other threads on here, but none of the suggestions worked:
[Assets 2 field not working properly within 2.6 relationship](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10847/assets-2-field-not-working-properly-within-2-6-relationship)

I am using EE 2.8.1 with Assets 2.4

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.
And I might have the solution for you:

```
{suggested_products}
    {suggested_products:product_images parse="inward"}
        {url}
    {/suggested_products:product_images}
{/suggested_products}
```

Comment: More info: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order